# Error parsing file: LWC Metadata Xml Parser: Unexpected element: runtimeNamespace

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, sfdx-plugin

I am trying to deploy an LWC and get this error : "Error parsing file: LWC Metadata Xml Parser: Unexpected element: runtimeNamespace". 
Here is the code of my js-meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>    
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>    
    <masterLabel>button_green</masterLabel>    
    <description>Button green</description>
    <runtimeNamespace>vlocity_cmt<runtimeNamespace>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

[image: VS code]

Answer (score 3):

I realised there is a typing error.
The runtimeNamespace tag is not closed correctly, I missed the "/"

Comment: This element is not part of the specification for this file's content (as mentioned by Martin Lezer in his answer). Why do you have it here?

Comment: It is for Vlocity LWC

Answer (score 2):

Well, the `runtimeNamespace` tag doesn't exist in the possible configuration file tags.

Here's a link to the documentation : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags